# Why does calling a function and not passing in a value with one parameter work but for more doesn't?

Tags: swift

why does the first function call not yield any error while the second function call yields an error? I'm not invoking a function but simply calling it. The difference between the two functions are the number of parameters.

```
func hello(firstName: String) {
print("Hello \(firstName)")
}
hello(firstName:)

func hello(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
print("Hello \(firstName) \(lastName)")
}
hello(firstName:, lastName:)
```

Comment: It's because, oh wait, where is my crystal ball to see the type of error you get?

Comment: In the first case, you are making a statement that has a function signature, in the second, if you want to do the same, you have to add '_' since you are making a list of arguments, but not passing a value. -> func(a: _, b: _)

Answer (score 2):

[The Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097) does not contain a easy-to-read description, but your first code is a valid expression in Swift, which returns a closure of type `(String)->Void`:

```
func hello(firstName: String) {
    print("Hello \(firstName)")
}

var closure: (String)->Void = hello(firstName:)
closure("Taro") //->Hello Taro
```

In your second code, `hello(firstName:, lastName:)` is not a valid expression in Swift, but `hello(firstName: lastName:)` is valid:

```
func hello(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    print("Hello \(firstName) \(lastName)")
}
//hello(firstName:, lastName:) //<-invalid
var closure2: (String, String)->Void = hello(firstName: lastName:)
closure2("Taro", "Yamada") //->Hello Taro Yamada
```

Maybe you have ever seen this sort of notations inside `#selector()`, but such notations can be used also outside `#selector()` as shown above.

Comment: "The Swift Book does not contain an easy-to-read description" — you are a master of understatement